# Adding text above background image to uiswitch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, background-image, uisegmentedcontrol

My custom UISegmented control has background images [for each state]. **How do I add text above the images [for each state, meaning that when index 0 will be selected I will have a specific color and font] ?**

Here's how my UISegmented control looks like:

```
UISegmentedControl *customUISC=[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ON",@"OFF",nil] autorelease]];

    [customUISC setFrame:CGRectMake(11,14,298,28)];
    customUISC.selectedSegmentIndex=0;
    customUISC.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

    [customUISC setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstTabActive.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [customUISC setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SecondTab.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [customUISC addTarget:self action:@selector(checkOnOffState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and the checkOnOffState method looks like:

```
-(IBAction)checkOnOffState:(id)sender{

UISegmentedControl *iSeg=(UISegmentedControl *)sender;

if(iSeg.selectedSegmentIndex==0){

    [iSeg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstTabActive.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [iSeg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SecondTab.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}
else {

    [iSeg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstTab.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [iSeg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SecondTabActive.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're after, but could you just make use of UILabels (positioned above the images). You could then change the colours and text quite easily using myLabel.text and myLabel.textColor.

Hope this helps in some way!

Comment: @Job W 09: I already tried to add the text as a subview using UILabel but its placed under the images...